# How to share data object across all react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I am fetching data from wordpress and storing it in data object. How can I share that data object across all components in React ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a library like Redux

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how complex your application is, Redux/MobX/Context etc. are  likely overkill. React's standard state/props may serve your needs as is.

Store your data in a parent component's state, then pass as props down through your sub-components wherever necessary.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flux-Pattern to share data between all components. React is a library and not a framework. You have to build the environment-pattern by your self. The most common way is to use "redux" with "redux-thunk" or "redux-saga".

Check Redux -> (https://redux.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Reach for Redux :
https://redux.js.org/

Store the object in a Redux Store.

Wrap your root App component in a Redux Provider like so:

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <App />
</Provider
```

Then the data can be available to any component if you use Redux connect(), like so :

```
class MyCless extends React.Component {
  ...
}

export default connect()(MyClass)
```

I also know that Redux Thunk (https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) is used for combining fetch/ajax requests with Redux.